# Oracle - Is it possible to "set" values inside case statement during update as below?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to "set" values inside case statement during update as below ?

```
UPDATE TABLE1
  CASE WHEN COL1 = 'A' THEN SET COL2 = 10, COL3 = 20, COL4 = 30
       WHEN COL1 IN ('B','N') THEN SET COL2 = 1, COL3 = 5, COL4 = 7
       WHEN COL1 = 'D' THEN SET COL2 = 11, COL3 = 13, COL4 = 17
       ELSE SET COL2 = 0, COL3 = 0, COL4 = 0
  END;
```

Answer (score 7):

The corresponding valid syntax would be like this.

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET
  COL2 = (CASE WHEN COL1 = 'A' THEN 10
               WHEN COL1 IN ('B','N') THEN 1
               WHEN COL1 = 'D' THEN 11
               ELSE 0
          END), 
  COL3 = (CASE WHEN COL1 = 'A' THEN 20
               WHEN COL1 IN ('B','N') THEN 5
               WHEN COL1 = 'D' THEN 13
               ELSE 0
          END), 
  COL4 = (CASE WHEN COL1 = 'A' THEN 30
               WHEN COL1 IN ('B','N') THEN 7
               WHEN COL1 = 'D' THEN 17
               ELSE 0
          END);
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to avoid an update for each column with case statement.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this via `case`, you would have to repeat the `case` for each field (as demonstrated by @MaheswaranRavisankar). That's just the way `case` works. An alternative would be to fabricate a sub-query that provides the same results. While this is longer, it does group related values together, which may be more readable/easier to maintain.

Given the need to set all non-matching values to zero, I would solve that by setting all values to zero first, then updating the matches the appropriate value.

```
UPDATE table1
SET    col2 = 0, col3 = 0, col4 = 0;

UPDATE table1
SET    (col2, col3, col4) =
          (SELECT a.col2, a.col3, a.col4
           FROM   (SELECT 'A' AS col1,
                          10 AS col2,
                          20 AS col3,
                          30 AS col4
                   FROM   DUAL
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'B' AS col1,
                          5 AS col2,
                          5 AS col3,
                          7 AS col4
                   FROM   DUAL
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'N' AS col1,
                          5 AS col2,
                          5 AS col3,
                          7 AS col4
                   FROM   DUAL
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'D' AS col1,
                          13 AS col2,
                          7 AS col3,
                          17 AS col4
                   FROM   DUAL) a
           WHERE  a.col1 = table1.col1);
```

This also hints at another option: perhaps you should consider creating a table with these values, rather than embedding them in the SQL.

Comment: I tried your approach, but it errors with `SQL Error: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns
01789. 00000 -  "query block has incorrect number of result columns"`

Comment: Of course you could change your dml statement from `SET    (col2, col3, col4)` to `SET    (col1, col2, col3, col4) ` and this will produce the desired results.  All in all, a solid answer.

Comment: The answer's been updated to resolve the issue that @Patrick raised.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to do a MERGE, with one exception.  You can update the table in a single merge statement as follows, except your logic to update all non-matching rows to 0's.

```
SQL> create table tab1
(
col1 varchar2(10),
col2 number,
col3 number,
col4 number,
merge_flag char(1)
)
Table created.
SQL> insert into tab1 values ('A', 10,11,12,null)
1 row created.
SQL> insert into tab1 values ('B', 20,21,22,null)
1 row created.
SQL> insert into tab1 values ('C', 30,31,32,null)
1 row created.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> select * from tab1

COL1             COL2       COL3       COL4 MERGE_FLAG
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A                  10         11         12           
B                  20         21         22           
C                  30         31         32           

3 rows selected.
SQL> merge into tab1 t
using (
    select 'A' as col1, 10 as col2, 20 as col3, 30 as col4 from dual
    union
    select 'B' as col1, 1 as col2, 5 as col3, 7 as col4 from dual
    union
    select 'N' as col1, 1 as col2, 5 as col3, 7 as col4 from dual
    union
    select 'D' as col1, 11 as col2, 13 as col3, 17 as col4 from dual
) x
on (t.col1 = x.col1)
when matched then
    update set t.col2 = x.col2, t.col3 = x.col3, t.col4 = x.col4, t.merge_flag = 'X'
Merge successfully completed.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> select * from tab1

COL1             COL2       COL3       COL4 MERGE_FLAG
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A                  10         20         30 X         
B                   1          5          7 X         
C                  30         31         32           

3 rows selected.
```

You could run a single update after the merge to change all non matching rows with 0.

Comment: Alternately, you could set every row to all zeros first, then run the `merge`, which would remove the need for a `merge_flag` column.

Comment: the merge_flag column was just to illustrate what fields were being updated, they aren't needed for the merge.

Comment: It isn't needed  for the merge, but, in order to update values that aren't merged to zero, you would need to know which rows were merged. I had assumed that was its intent.

Comment: I see.  You wouldn't need to know which rows were merged, you'd just run an update where col1 not in the "merge" list ("x" in my example).